# Using Scipy's LowLevelCallable and numba cfunc to optimise a time based ode that takes multiple arrays as input

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, numba, ode

I want to optimise the solving of a system of time based ODE's by combining Numba's `cfunc` and scipy's `LowLevelCallable` functionality to greatly speed up `odeint()`. However, i am having trouble finding out what the exact syntax is for the correct solution.

My (non-optimised) code that works looks something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
from numba import types
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.integrate as si

# hours in the simulation
T_sim = 72 
# simulate fluctuating outside temp for 3 days
T_out = np.sin(np.linspace(0, T_sim, T_sim)/3.8) * 8 + 18 
# heat capacity of the air and floor
cap_air, cap_flr = 1, 10

def func(T, t):
    T_air, T_flr= T[0], T[1]
    t_ = int(t)
    H_airOut = 4 * U_vent[t_] * (T_air - T_out[t_])
    H_blowAir = U_blow[t_]
    H_airFlr = (T_air - T_flr)
    dT_air = ((H_blowAir 
               - H_airOut
               - H_airFlr) / cap_air)
    dT_flr = H_airFlr / cap_flr
    return dT_air, dT_flr

T0 = [16, 18] # starting temperature for T_air and T_flr
t_eval = np.linspace(0, T_sim-1, T_sim-1)
U_blow = np.full(T_sim, 0.1) # control for the heating
U_vent = np.full(T_sim, 0.3) # control for the ventilation
result = si.odeint(func,T0,t_eval)

# this piece of code is a standin for the real code, where func() is run 
# tens of thousands of times. All variables are constant, except for the 
# two arrays U_blow and U_vent
for _ in range(10):
    U_blow = np.random.rand(T_sim)
    U_vent = np.random.rand(T_sim)
    result = si.odeint(func,T0,t_eval)

plt.plot(result[:, 0], label='T_air')
plt.plot(result[:, 1], label='T_flr')
plt.plot(T_out[:-1], label='T_out')
plt.legend()
```

Based on other SO posts, im pretty sure that the solution should look something the code below, but i cant get it to work myself. The problem would have been much easier if there were only some variables changing between runs, but this is not the case, as I need to be able to vary the arrays `U_blow` & `U_vent` between runs.

```
import scipy as sp
from numba.types import float64, CPointer, intc

def jit_integrand_function(integrand_function):
    jitted_function = nb.jit(integrand_function, nopython=True)

    @nb.cfunc(float64(intc, CPointer(float64)))
    def wrapped(n, xx):
        return jitted_function(xx[0], xx[1])
    return sp.LowLevelCallable(wrapped.ctypes)

@jit_integrand_function
def func(T, t):
    T_air, T_flr= T[0], T[1]
    t_ = int(t)
    H_airOut = 4 * U_vent[t_] * (T_air - T_out[t_])
    H_blowAir = U_blow[t_]
    H_airFlr = (T_air - T_flr)
    dT_air = ((H_blowAir 
               - H_airOut
               - H_airFlr) / cap_air)
    dT_flr = H_airFlr / cap_flr
    return dT_air, dT_flr

T0 = [16, 18] # starting temperature for T_air and T_flr
t_eval = np.linspace(0, T_sim-1, T_sim-1)

for _ in range(10):
    U_blow = np.random.rand(T_sim)
    U_vent = np.random.rand(T_sim)
    result = si.odeint(func,T0,t_eval, (U_blow, U_vent))

plt.plot(result[:, 0], label='T_air')
plt.plot(result[:, 1], label='T_flr')
plt.plot(T_out[:-1], label='T_out')
plt.legend()
```

As a sidenote, my full model is not numerically stable enough for the euler forward integration method to work, so that is not option.

Comment: Out of curiosity: The documentation of the [odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) function does not seem to mention that it accepts `LowLevelCallable`s as arguments (as opposed to, for example [integrate.quad](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quad.html#scipy.integrate.quad)). Are you sure that your approach is supported in `scipy`?

Comment: @hfhc2 You seem to be right in that `odeint` cant be used here. However, that piece of code was mainly to prove that I tried to get to a solution myself, but failed. When I posted this I thought that I either made some kind of syntax error, or that there was an alternative and much easier method to achieve the same thing. I only really care about solving my problem, I dont care if that solution uses `scipy` or not. That is also the reason that the bounty is asking about "a general perfomance gain" and not about `scipy` specifically.

Comment: I really feel that a solution to my problem exist, i can barely believe that I really have to swap languages to be able to improve the performance of a large ODE. Surely that shouldnt be impossible to do in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My attempt at an answer is as follows, working of this complete example:

```py
import scipy as sp
import scipy.integrate as si
import numpy as np

# hours in the simulation
T_sim = 72
# simulate fluctuating outside temp for 3 days
T_out = np.sin(np.linspace(0, T_sim, T_sim) / 3.8) * 8 + 18
# heat capacity of the air and floor
cap_air, cap_flr = 1, 10

U_blow = np.random.rand(T_sim)
U_vent = np.random.rand(T_sim)


def example_rhs(T, t, U_blow, U_vent):
    T_air, T_flr = T[0], T[1]
    t_ = int(t)
    H_airOut = 4 * U_vent[t_] * (T_air - T_out[t_])
    H_blowAir = U_blow[t_]
    H_airFlr = (T_air - T_flr)
    dT_air = ((H_blowAir - H_airOut - H_airFlr) / cap_air)
    dT_flr = H_airFlr / cap_flr

    return dT_air, dT_flr


# starting temperature for T_air and T_flr
T0 = [16, 18]
t_eval = np.linspace(0,
                     T_sim - 1,
                     T_sim - 1)

# Repeat the integration a couple of times to increase accuracy
for i in range(100):
    si.odeint(example_rhs, T0, t_eval, args=(U_blow, U_vent))
```

To analyze the performance of any python code, I would start by using `cProfile` via `python -mcProfile -s cumtime test.py`

This gives me the following (abridged):

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
[...]
      100    0.001    0.000    2.021    0.020 _odepack_py.py:28(odeint)
      100    0.843    0.008    2.017    0.020 {built-in method scipy.integrate._odepack.odeint}

[...]
   973000    1.174    0.000    1.174    0.000 test.py:16(example_rhs)
```

As we see, the code spends ~2 seconds in the `odeint` function, which is a [built-in](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/integrate/_odepackmodule.c) function, which calls a Fortran code to do the solving. With this time, the python-based rhs is called 973000 times, i.e., 9730 per integration, though this may vary for different inputs. However, only about half ~1.174 seconds are spent within the right hand side. So, even if your callback would be so optimized that its running time would be zero, you would still need ~0.8 seconds for the entire operation. Since this time is spent in a Fortran code, I don't think that there is a way to speed up that part. So, I don't think an order of magnitude is possible, at least with respect to this particular instance (but maybe you original instance behaves differently?).

It is a shame that `LowLevelCallable`s are apparently not supported for ODE integration in `scipy`, it seems like that would be an obvious addition (though maybe there is something preventing that?!)

Edit: As per Jérôme Richards comments: The suite is indeed old, so maybe another library will help. You could try [sundials](https://computing.llnl.gov/projects/sundials), which is a pretty state-of-the-art ODE / DAE solver (about the best that I know), which also has a python [interface](https://pypi.org/project/pycvodes/). If your ODE is stiff, you probably want to use a BDF solver, in which case you should provide the Jacobian of your right-hand side as well, provided that your model is sufficiently smooth (see the comments).

Comment: Thanks for your answer hfhc2! It is very clear to me now that my problem cant be solved using `odeint`. But the bounty is not specifcally for a method that uses `odeint`, I am only interested in improving perfomance in any way possible. Can you think of an alternative solution?

Comment: While the question shows interesting information, the `odeint` function does a lot of Python-related operation that may take a significant time compared to the `LSODA` Fortran call. For example the `ode_function` function create new object and this requires allocations and reference counting that are quite expensive (IDK comparing to the `LSODA` function call but it should be certainly not negligible based on the provided performance results).

Comment: A possible fix consists in writing an alternative implementation calling the Fortran function directly from a Cython code for example. This may not be simple to do, but certainly simpler and faster than a generic code dealing with Python objects. Note that `LSODA` can be called from SciPy though it may add some overhead compared to a native call (even in Cython).

Comment: `LSODA` is a Fortran function implemented based on a 40 years old algorithm. Since its integration in Scipy 22 years ago based on a 32 years-old file, no optimizations has been performed (just few bug fixes). It makes sense since its code is ugly and really hard to read. Computer have changed a lot since 32 years starting from SIMD units, multi-cores, instruction-level parallelism, etc. floating-point operations are cheap these days while they was very expensive in the 90's. I strongly believe this code can be optimized assuming someone can fully understand it ;) .

Comment: @Rafnus: Another thing I noticed: You are casting the integration time `t` to an integer `t_` and then access an array based on that index. As far as I see, this makes your right-hand side non-differentiable with respect to the model time. Is that intentional, or would you prefer a smooth right-hand side instead?